# Can creators of RSA read all encoded messages?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, prime-factoring

According to this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers each RSA version uses one single constant long number which is hard to factor.

Is this right?

For example, RSA-100 uses number

```
1522605027922533360535618378132637429718068114961380688657908494580122963258952897654000350692006139
```

which was factored in 1991.

Meanwhile RSA-210 uses number

```
245246644900278211976517663573088018467026787678332759743414451715061600830038587216952208399332071549103626827191679864079776723243005600592035631246561218465817904100131859299619933817012149335034875870551067
```

which was not factored yet.

My question is: doesn't this mean that CREATORS of any specific RSA version KNOW the factor numbers and can consequently READ all encoded messages? If they don't know factorization then how they could generate a number?

Comment: That page says absolutely nothing whatsoever about encryption, or the implementation of the RSA algorithm.

Comment: Yes, you need to use some inference :)

Comment: No, you don't, because the RSA numbers have nothing to do with RSA encryption, except that they're large primes.

Comment: Ok I understand your point, but I need something else.

Comment: Well, if it helps, the answer to your question is "no", and you're reading the wrong wikipedia article.

Comment: Does this mean that actual semiprime numbers, used while encoding, are generated on-the-fly and are not global for given key-size?

Comment: Yes, see the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)#Key_generation article. It states that the primes factors should be chosen at random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those numbers are just **sample** random numbers, which are used by RSA to judge the adequacy of the algorithm. The RSA asymmetric-key algorithm itself relies on the difficulty in factorizing numbers of a large size, for security.

The approximate time or difficulty in factoring these numbers is an indicator of how other such numbers used in the algorithm will fare against the amount of computational power we have.

These numbers, which were challenges, are described as follows.

**(Quoting from [Reference](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2094#WhyIs))**

> The RSA challenge numbers were generated using a secure process that
> guarantees that the factors of each number cannot be obtained by any
> method other than factoring the published value. No one, not even RSA
> Laboratories, knows the factors of any of the challenge numbers. The
> generation took place on a Compaq laptop PC with no network connection
> of any kind. The process proceeded as follows:
>
> First, 30,000 random
> bytes were generated using a ComScire QNG hardware random number
> generator, attached to the laptop's parallel port.
>
> The random bytes
> were used as the seed values for the B_GenerateKeyPair function, in
> version 4.0 of the RSA BSAFE library.
>
> The private portion of the
> generated keypair was discarded. The public portion was exported, in
> DER format to a disk file.
>
> The moduli were extracted from the DER
> files and converted to decimal for posting on the Web page.
>
> The
> laptop's hard drive was destroyed.

When it becomes fairly trivial and quick, to reliably factorize numbers of a particular size, it usually implies it is time to move to a longer number.

Comment: OK explanation, although obviously the number is not fully random. The number is derived using a random number generator, but the number itself needs to comply with the RSA requirements. That's why generating an RSA key pair takes so long.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Ron was wrong, Whit is right](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/064.pdf). It is a detailed analysis of duplicate RSA key use and the use of RSA keys using common factors (the problem you describe). There is a lot in the article but, to quote from its conclusion:

> We checked the computational properties of millions of public keys
>   that we collected on the web. The majority does not seem to suffer from
>   obvious weaknesses and can be expected to provide the expected level
>   of security. We found that on the order of 0.003% of public keys is
>   incorrect, which does not seem to be unacceptable.

Yes, it is a problem and the problem will continue to grow but the sheer number of possible keys means the problem is not too serious, at least not yet. Note that the article does not cover the increasing ease of brute forcing shorter RSA keys, either.

Note that this is not an issue with the RSA algorithm or the random number generators used to generate keys (although the paper does mention seeding may still be an issue). It is the difficulty of checking a newly generated key against an ever expanding list of existing keys from an arbitrary, sometimes disconnected device. This differs from the [known weak keys for DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_key), for example, where the weak keys are known upfront.

Comment: Voted down as you let it seem like this is a problem inherent to RSA. It isn't, it is a problem with the random number generators that were used. The RSA key space is large, very large for high bit counts. If it wasn't, you could simply brute force it.

Comment: @owlstead I have clarified that it is a problem with key generation, not the algorithm itself.

Comment: Have you read the conclusion of the paper? "This may indicate that proper seeding of random number generators is still a problematic issue." You've still not reflected that in your answer (and I mistakenly voted up instead of undoing my downvote). In other words, it *is* the specific random number generator used.

Comment: @owlstead Yes, I have read the conclusion and I have added a note to the answer. However, I if proper seeding was an issue, I suspect weak keys would occur more frequently than 0.003%. I think the paper is trying to explain why the 0.003% occurred rather than make a general comment about entropy used for RSA key generation.

Comment: Normally you don't have to check against known keys. In our company we do check if the key modulus was generated before, but that is not because we are afraid of collisions. It's more a safeguard against problems with the rng or key pair generation method.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the paper here; they tested keys found on the internet. Those would have been generated by a big plurality of systems. Some of those would have used properly seeded key generation algorithms, but some of those would not. They mention a specific implementation that was at risk; anything relying on the broken Debian RNG. They would not have any identical prime factors if they had used a well seeded, correctly programmed RSA key gen.